# Как написать функцию вывода дня недели и месяца + 1 день?

Tags: php, дата, время, datetime, timestamp

Есть две функции:

Функция для получения даты

```
// Дата по-русски
function getDateRus(){
$monthes = array(
    1 => 'Января', 2 => 'Февраля', 3 => 'Марта', 4 => 'Апреля',
    5 => 'Мая', 6 => 'Июня', 7 => 'Июля', 8 => 'Августа',
    9 => 'Сентября', 10 => 'Октября', 11 => 'Ноября', 12 => 'Декабря'
);
return ( (int)date('d') . ' ' . $monthes[(date('n'))] . date(' Y'));
}
```

И функция для получения дня недели:

```
// День недели по-русски
function getDayRus(){
$days = array(
    'Воскресенье', 'Понедельник', 'Вторник', 'Среда',
    'Четверг', 'Пятница', 'Суббота'
);
return $days[(date('w'))];
}
```

которая выводит текущий день:

`echo "Сегодня:" . getDateRus() . ", " . getDayRus();`

Как переделать ее, чтобы можно было выводить дни: +1 день, +2 дня, +3 дня?

Comment: никак не переделать - другую написать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в функции параметр, который будет обозначать число добавляемых дней, и установите значение по умолчанию в 0.

```
function getDateRus($add= 0){
    $months = [
        1 => 'Января', 2 => 'Февраля', 3 => 'Марта', 4 => 'Апреля',
        5 => 'Мая',    6 => 'Июня',    7 => 'Июля',  8 => 'Августа',
        9 => 'Сентября', 10 => 'Октября', 11 => 'Ноября', 12 => 'Декабря'
    ];

    $d = strtotime("+$add days");
    $m = $months[date("n", $d)];
    return date("d $m Y", $d);
}
```

Comment: teran я немного дополнил функцию под свои нужды, но при выводе даты, которая попадает на Воскресенье, она выводится как: `Воскре2019-12-01T15:08:52+01:00енье, 01 Декабря` Как можно поправить?

Comment: @VladZaev собирайте результат как раньше у вас было через конкатенацию, без использования `date("d $m Y")`, как в данном примере.

Answer (score 1):

Оставлю как вариант

```
function getDateRus($date = 0)
{
    $monthes = array(
        1 => 'Января', 2 => 'Февраля', 3 => 'Марта', 4 => 'Апреля',
        5 => 'Мая', 6 => 'Июня', 7 => 'Июля', 8 => 'Августа',
        9 => 'Сентября', 10 => 'Октября', 11 => 'Ноября', 12 => 'Декабря'
    );

    return (int) date('d', $date) . ' ' . $monthes[date('n', $date)] . " " . date('Y', $date);
}

function getDayRus($date)
{
    $days = array(
        'Воскресенье', 'Понедельник', 'Вторник', 'Среда',
        'Четверг', 'Пятница', 'Суббота'
    );
    return $days[date('w', $date)];
}

$increment = 10; // Cколько дней добавляем
$date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "+ $increment day");

echo "Сегодня: " . getDateRus($date) . ", " . getDayRus($date);
```

Comment: а как можно эту переменную `$date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "+ $increment day");` поместить в функцию, что вызывать ее через echo?

Answer (score 1):

как вариант

```
$days = "+2"; // +3, +4 etc.

function getDateRus ($days, $stringDate)
{
    $dayOfWeek=['Воскресенье','Понедельник','Вторник','Среда','Четверг','Пятница','Суббота'];
    $mothers_en = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    $monthes_ru = ['Января','Февраля','Марта',
               'Апреля','Мая','Июня',
               'Июля','Августа','Сентября',
               'Октября','Ноября','Декабря'];

    $finalDate = (date('d M Y', strtotime($days . 'day')));
    $finalDateRaplaced = str_replace($mothers_en, $monthes_ru, $finalDate);

    if ($stringDate) $finalDateRaplaced .=  ', ' . $dayOfWeek[(date('w'))];

    return $finalDateRaplaced;
}

// echo getDateRus($days, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за решения! У меня сработал такой полный вариант:

```
    function getDateRus($add= 0){
    $months = [
        1 => 'Января', 2 => 'Февраля', 3 => 'Марта', 4 => 'Апреля',
        5 => 'Мая',    6 => 'Июня',    7 => 'Июля',  8 => 'Августа',
        9 => 'Сентября', 10 => 'Октября', 11 => 'Ноября', 12 => 'Декабря'
    ];

    $days = ["Sunday" => "Воскресенье", "Monday" => "Понедельник", "Tuesday" => "Вторник", "Wednesday" => "Среда", "Thursday" => "Четверг", "Friday" => "Пятница", "Saturday" => "Суббота"];

    $d = strtotime("+$add days");
    $m = $months[date("n", $d)];

    $wd = $days[date("l", $d)];

    return date("$wd, d $m", $d);
}
```

Может еще кому пригодится.